# How to DataFilters in Google Sheets using API in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to filter out data in google sheets and trying to understand below code.

Please guide me where in below code can I specify the column/field to filter from and where to apply the values to filter?

Also if possible please share some example I'm new to this.

Thanks in advance.

```
Source: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/getByDataFilter
            SheetsService sheetsService = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = GetCredential(),
                ApplicationName = "Google-SheetsSample/0.1",
            });

            // The spreadsheet to request.
            string spreadsheetId = "my-spreadsheet-id";  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

            // The DataFilters used to select which ranges to retrieve from
            // the spreadsheet.
            List<Data.DataFilter> dataFilters = new List<Data.DataFilter>();  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

            // True if grid data should be returned.
            // This parameter is ignored if a field mask was set in the request.
            bool includeGridData = false;  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

            // TODO: Assign values to desired properties of `requestBody`:
            Data.GetSpreadsheetByDataFilterRequest requestBody = new Data.GetSpreadsheetByDataFilterRequest();
            requestBody.DataFilters = dataFilters;
            requestBody.IncludeGridData = includeGridData;

            SpreadsheetsResource.GetByDataFilterRequest request = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.GetByDataFilter(requestBody, spreadsheetId);

            // To execute asynchronously in an async method, replace `request.Execute()` as shown:
            Data.Spreadsheet response = request.Execute();
```

Comment: For better understanding, I recommend you to play with the `Try this API` before implementing the request into your code. Have also a look at the [dataFilter resource](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DataFilter)

Comment: @ziganotschka thanks for your help.

Do I need to pass on list of string to Data.DataFilter and 
is requestBody like a range/area in sheet? 
Where can I add Fields filter type like developerMetadataLookup or a1Range?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57719239/how-can-i-use-the-google-sheets-v4-api-getbydatafilter-to-return-a-specific-ro) should be useful for you.